# Is there a way to select and download file from google drive using react js google drive picker and python?

Tags: python, reactjs, google-drive-picker

I want to download file from google drive using React google drive picker and python flask as a backend. And I'm kinda having hard time to do this.
here's my code in frontend but i still dont have a code yet in backend. Or can i do this in react js alone without using python as a backend?

```js
  const [openPicker, data, authResponse] = useDrivePicker();  

  const handleOpenPicker = () => {
    openPicker({
      clientId: "",
      developerKey: "",
      viewId: "SPREADSHEETS",
      // token: token, // pass oauth token in case you already have one
      showUploadView: true,
      showUploadFolders: true,
      supportDrives: true,
      multiselect: false,
      // customViews: customViewsArray, // custom view
    })
  };
```